# How does one apply css design properly so that in runs on a website from a separate document?

Tags: css

How does one apply CSS design so that it runs in a website from a separate folder?
I wrote this to make some font red but it won't apply

```
<head>
  //...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your style should be in a <style> tag in the head of the document.

Comment: The css code needs to be in `css/style.css'. Alternatively, @LiamStrilchuk suggestion would also work and you wouldn't need to put the css in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a folder named css with a file called `style.css` , where the data inside that file will be `h1
 { color: red; }`

This should work, if u followed every step accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original code:

```
<head>
  //...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Your `h1` style should be in the file "css/style.css", not in the html file.

Your link to the stylesheet `href="css/style.css"` is a *relative* link, so "style.css" must be in a subdirectory of the directory where the html file is, for example if this file is "index.html" and it is in a directory `.../web/docs/index.html` then style.css would have to be in `.../web/docs/css/style.css`

This would look like

```
<head> <!-- doc/index.html -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

/* doc/css/style.css */
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

I generally use either (1) *absolute* paths for stylesheets, so my link might look like `href="/css/style.css"` or (2) a stylesheet in the same directory with the html file, which would be `href="style.css"`  -- but that's my preference, not a requirement.